# Is the POSIX `[:print:]` character class the same as Unicode `\P{C}`?

Tags: javascript, ruby, unicode, encoding, posix

Ruby's `\p{print}` character class in regex does not seem to match JavaScript's `\P{C}` class. For example, Ruby handles U+00AD (SOFT HYPHEN) as printable:

```rb
0x00ad.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).match?(/\p{print}/) # => true
```

whereas Node.js handles the character as not printable

```js
/\P{C}/u.test(String.fromCharCode(0x00ad)) // false
```

I believe Ruby's Onigmo regex engine follows POSIX, and a website like [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) tells that POSIX `[:print:]` corresponds to Unicode `\P{C}`. A website like [this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm) tells that indeed U+00AD  belongs to 'Other, Format' (`Cf`) category, a subset of 'Other', (`C`) category. But they do not match.

Is either side mistaken, or are POSIX `[:print:]` character class and  Unicode `\P{C}` actually different things? If they are different, what are the idea behind the respective classes? And, is there a POSIX character class counterpart to Unicode `\P{C}`, or a Unicode counterpart to POSIX `[:print:]`?